# Dymo Lablewriter 450 installation keeps failing

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printing, printer

User used to have a DYMO labelwriter SE450 that worked perfectly fine for months, no issues. Windows 7 pro, absolutely no configuration changes have been made that would stop it working.

It recently stopped working. DYMO support gave a list of steps that i followed to the letter and the printer still did not install. The DYMO software installs fine, then i have the printer plugged in, but in device manager it shows as 'unknown device'. I cannot add it via add printers.

We have even replaced this older model with a current gen 450. the same exact issue occurs. I am desperate for an answer here as DYMO support are just giving me the same old spiel. I have tried this several times now, logged in as an admin user, And it JUST. WONT. WORK

The major barrier is that i am in a different country to the user having issues, so DYMO will not get involved in troubleshooting unless i am on site..

given steps:

1. Close Dymo Label Software
2. Disconnect the Dymo printer from the computer
3. Restart your computer with the printer disconnected
4. Go to Start > Control Panel > Programs & Features > and remove Dymo Label Software v8
5. Once the uninstall is completed you go and remove the installation folder:

32bit - C:\Program Files\DYMO (v.8.x.x)

64bit - C:\Program Files (x86)\DYMO (v.8.x.x)

5.1 Go to C:\ProgramData and remove the DYMO folder

5.2 Go to C:\Users-Your-User Name-\Documents and remove the DYMO Label folder

6. Go to this hidden folder - C:\Users-Your-User Name-\App Data\Local\ , and remove DYMO and Sandford,_L.P folders
7. Reboot the computer once more, to make sure that the changes have been made. Still keep the printer disconnected.
8. Once the computer has restarted, download and install the latest version of the software >Click here< to install DLS 8.5.3.
9. Once the installation is completed, then connect the printer directly to the computer, do not use a USB hub or docking station, and make sure that Windows finds and installs the printer correctly.
10. Open up Control Panel > Device & Printers and see if the printer shows up as a Printer

Comment: This may not be a problem with the device or the software.  I've had USB cables go bad and cause trouble like this--(Windows still recognizes that some device is plugged in, but can't determine what it is).  Can you swap the USB cable for another one?

Comment: I thought of that, I have tried multiple cables, old and new and two different printers (Labelwriter SE450 and Labelwriter 450)